Unable to write to mountd custom EFS for Sagemaker studio
I followed the instructions here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/domain-custom-efs.html
I am able to get to the point where I am able to, at the start of a Jupyterlab space, see the option to mount a custom efs, mount it, and see it in my space. However, when I try to write to it, such as creating a notebook inside custom-file-systems/efs/fs-0913ccfbff134d519, I get a:
Permission denied: custom-file-systems/efs/fs-0913ccfbff134d519/Untitled.ipynb
I have set up my file system policy to allow:
"elasticfilesystem:ClientMount",
"elasticfilesystem:ClientWrite",
"elasticfilesystem:ClientRootAccess"
and likewise for my iam policy for the user role of my sagemaker user.
From what I have read online, there are two potential reasons:

My fs is read-only: https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/efs-enable-read-write-access
I am missing some kind of posix permissions. It is commonly resolved through something like an access point: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/access-points.html

Does anyone have any idea how to resolve this? Are my hypotheses correct? Unsure why following the instructions does not work. I don't see a way to mount an access point on to sagemaker studio, for example.

When you create a new EFS volume and attach it to a SageMaker domain, the SageMaker users will not have the appropriate permissions to write to the volume.
By default, an EFS volume only allows root (uid 0) to write to the volume. The gid for SageMaker users is 1001. The uid range starts at 200001, and you can determine a particular user's uid by describing the user profile and looking at HomeEfsFileSystemUid. You can find more details here.
The most straightforward way to adjust the permissions is to mount the EFS volume on an EC2 instance and change the permissions there. I recommend creating a directory for each SageMaker user and allowing only that specific user to perform write operations.
After you have adapted the permissions of the EFS volume, you should be able to use it within SageMaker according to the configuration you described.
